# Core Animation flip view in middle and replace content

Tags: iphone, core-animation, uilabel, flip

I'm trying to put a animation in each table view cell.

The view should take an array of NSStrings. If it has more than 1 string i want a animation, and this is what I'm not really sure of.

I have a UILabel, what I want to do is to have a vertical flip, but it shouldn't be the entire view. I want the top half to fall down (and bottom half of the next strings uilabel to fall down over it)
Look on this image http://www.fazyluckers.com/extensions/InlineImages/image.jpg.php?AttachmentID=209 but per uilabel instead of character.

So, I guess there are two questions.

How do I active the flip in the middle? (I already managed to get the vertical flip work with a CABasicAnimation)

For iOS 3 (I know its old, but some ppl still uses it) whats the best way to repeat the animation with the updated next string? is it in animationDidFinish... and update the strings and start the same animation again?

Comment: Yes, you need to implement animationDidStop selector to go for next string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this.

http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2010/04/10/creating-an-ipad-flip-clock-with-core-animation/